# Ordering MySql Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to sort a mysql table by a few different columns. Here's the table:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|     id     |  parent_id |  ordering  |    level   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      1     |     0      |      0     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      2     |     0      |      2     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      3     |     0      |      3     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      4     |     0      |      4     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      5     |     2      |      0     |      1     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      6     |     0      |      1     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

And this is the result I'd like to achieve:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|     id     |  parent_id |  ordering  |    level   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      1     |     0      |      0     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      6     |     0      |      1     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      2     |     0      |      2     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      5     |     2      |      0     |      1     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      3     |     0      |      3     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      4     |     0      |      4     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

As you can (hopefully) see, I would like to sort the items by ordering and parent_id. I would prefer, if possible, to use a single query. If this is not possible, I can use a PHP loop in combination with the query. I'd like to stay away from multiple queries if at all possible.

I need a way to sort so that a row with a `parent_id` such as row with `id=5` is below it's "parent row" (row with `id=2`). 'ordering' is based on 'level'.

The closest I've come is by sorting this with:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ordering,id,parent_id`

Which returns:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|     id     |  parent_id |  ordering  |    level   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      1     |     0      |      0     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      5     |     2      |      0     |      1     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      6     |     0      |      1     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      2     |     0      |      2     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      3     |     0      |      3     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      4     |     0      |      4     |      0     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand how you consider the result sorted. Neither the values in `ordering` nor `parent_id` are in a sorted order.

Comment: Can you elaborate -- I don't see how ordering and parent_id are sorted at all...

Comment: If the rows were ordered 1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, then I would understand what you are asking.

Comment: Please add some more detail.  Describe what you have tried and what your results were.  This will help the SO community to assist you.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to sort by the `SUM` of the Ordering and Parent_Id columns?  Assuming those were both numeric data types, this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Parent_Id + Ordering, Id
```

Comment: Wow, an upvote just for reverse engineering that puzzle of a question.

Comment: @JohnFx -- lmao -- That's the only "ordering" I see in the example above :D

Comment: That was relatively a fast answer, owing to the fact most of the people didn't understand the question :) Your answer does look as if it satisfies his requirement though.

Answer (score 1):

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b4da/7)

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY parent_id + ordering, id
```